# HTTP Proxy Server Setup

Tags: c++, sockets, http, proxy

I'm writing an HTTP Proxy server in C++ for a class project. I can't seem to get the socket to accept a request sent to the server. I'm following the example here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) != 0)    {
    fprintf(stderr, "binding failure");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(listen(sockfd, 5) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "listening failure");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else cout << "Listening for connections on port " << PORTNUM << "\n";

//------------END SERVER SETUP--------------------------


//-----------LISTEN LOOP--------------------
char request_buffer[1024];
ssize_t bytes_recieved;
HttpRequest request;
string errorMessage;

while(1)    {
    cout << "say something";
    socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);
         ...
```

When I run the server and set it an HTTP Request (e.g. GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1), There's no response, as the socket never accepts this connection.

What am I doing wrong? The code compiles correctly, and I know the socket is bound to the port and listening for connections. However, it just gets stuck in the infinite loop, waiting for connections.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the request is sent? You could use packet sniffing tools such as Wireshark to trace incoming packets. What tool are you using to send packets to your server?

Comment: When you get an error from a system call such as `socket(), listen(), bind(), accept(), ...` you must print the error itself, not just some message of your own devising. Otherwise debugging becomes a mere guessing game. Use `perror()` or `WSAGetLastError()` and friends.